# multiple 'instances' of the same labelled field on the same page in Azure Form Recognizer custom model?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I was wondering if there is something I'm missing on dealing with multiple instances of the same labelled field in a Azure Form Recognizer Custom Model (with labels)?  Let's use the following (VERY simplified) document, for example:
[image]

Now, If I train a model to detect 'Name', 'DOB', and 'Company', I end up with results that look like:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Name": {
            "value_type": "string",
            "label_data": null,
            "value_data": {
                "page_number": 1,
                "text": "John R. Smith Ronald Johnson., Esquire",
                "bounding_box": [
                    [
                        0.57,
                        4.435
                    ],
                    [
                        1.8,
                        4.435
                    ],
                    [
                        1.8,
                        6.005
                    ],
                    [
                        0.57,
                        6.005
                    ]
                ],
                "field_elements": null
            },
            "name": "Name",
            "value": "John R. Smith Ronald Johnson., Esquire",
            "confidence": 1
        },
...
```

As you can see, there is no delimiter between each 'instance' of the `Name` field in the Azure Form Recognizer results JSON.  How should I train and/or deal with the Field results in a way that allows me to extract *each* instance of a given field from the document?

The first thing I tried, was marking the label name & the value for a field from the document and training on that.  For example, `Name: John R. Smith` and `Name: Ronald Johnson., Esquire` would be what i marked in FOTT as the `Name` field for this training example.  Then, I would split the result on `Name:`.  This seems fine in theory, but in practice I ended up with VERY low accuracy compared to selecting JUST the field value and training on those.

Answer (score -2):

Please label these as Name1 and Name2 to extract them as separate fields.

Comment: There could be arbitrarily many instances of each field type, per document template.  That's not a general solution.